# How to use extensions in XSD files properly?

Tags: xml, inheritance, xsd

In my case I have a two quite simple XSDs. First is `Person.xsd` with elements like: name, age and second (`Reader.xsd`) should inherit from `Person.xsd`. I use XMLSpy as a validator and it throws an errors. I'm beginner in XSD files, so I think it won't be hard to find a solution for my case.
Person.xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema elementFormDefault="qualified"
xmlns:p="http://www.demo.com"
targetNamespace="http://www.demo.com"
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<xs:complexType name="PersonType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="firstname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="lastname" type="xs:string"/>
        <xs:element name="age" type="xs:int"/>
    </xs:sequence>
    <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int"/>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="person" type="p:PersonType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Reader.xsd:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"  
xmlns:r="http://www.demo.com"
targetNamespace="http://www.demo.com"
elementFormDefault="qualified">
<xs:include schemaLocation="person.xsd"/>
<!--<xs:element name="person" type="p:PersonType"/>-->
<xs:complexType name="ReaderType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="PersonType"> // THERE IS A RED MARKER ('must 
refer to an existing simple or complex type')
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="bookId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" 
maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
            <xs:attribute name="id" type="xs:int" use="required"/>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="reader" type="r:ReaderType"/>

<xs:complexType name="ReadersType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="r:reader" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="readers" type="r:ReadersType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out. `reader.xsd` should be:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
xmlns:r="http://www.demo.com/reader" xmlns:p="http://www.demo.com/person" 
targetNamespace="http://www.demo.com/reader" elementFormDefault="qualified">

<xs:import namespace="http://www.demo.com/person" schemaLocation="person.xsd"/>

<xs:complexType name="ReaderType">
    <xs:complexContent>
        <xs:extension base="p:PersonType">
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="bookId" type="xs:int" minOccurs="0" 
maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:extension>
    </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="reader" type="r:ReaderType"/>

<xs:complexType name="ReadersType">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="r:reader" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>      
</xs:complexType>

<xs:element name="readers" type="r:ReadersType"/>

</xs:schema>
```

Answer (score 1):

The name of a complex type is in the targetNamespace of the containing schema document, so the name of your complex type is `{http://www.demo.com}PersonType`. Since the prefix `r` is bound to this namespace, you can refer to the type using the QName `base="r:PersonType"`.